# Applescript not clicking button in Chrome unless I double-click window while script runs

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, automation

I am using the following applescript in automator to

1. copy the contents of a field on a webpage open in Chrome to the clipboard and
2. click a button on that same webpage

While the copying works well, this is not successfully clicking the specified button unless I double-click into the Chrome tab I have open as the script begins to run. I am clicking "Run" in automator, then double clicking into the chrome window.

I've tried switching to safari (and adjusting the script), and have had the same issue there. Even if I click into the chrome tab I have open once, the script still won't click the button.

Any thoughts on what could be going on? This is very much a frankenstein script from other questions on here and elsewhere.

```
  delay 1


tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "document.getElementById('txt_Email'). value"
        
        set my_field to result
        set the clipboard to my_field
        

        delay 1
        
        
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            tell active tab of front window
                execute javascript "document.getElementById('file_memberFileName').click();"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 1
```

Comment: try bringing chrome to the front - `tell application "Google Chrome" to activate`

Comment: Thanks, though that doesn't seem to do the trick. Still have the same issue. If it helps with problem solving, the part of the script after what is included here is to keystroke cmd + g. After clicking the button (file_memberFileName), it should open up a file navigator, and the cmd+ g should open up a "go to" window. Instead, the cmd + g is just operating as a find within the chrome window, the same as cmd + f

Comment: Cmd/G in Chrome is 'find next'. What are you actually trying to get? "Go To" is a Finder command, & is Cmd/SHIFT/G. To use that, you'd have to switch to Finder.

Comment: oh yes you're right, command shift g is pressed down, and yes, it is in a finder window. This function is supposed to 1) copy a value (email address), click on an "attach document button which opens a file selector window, then cmd+shift+g, then enters a filepath and pastes in the email address to find a corresponding document that has been named after the email. It works well, but as I said, I need to double click in the chrome window. Not a big deal, but it makes it harder to run mindlessly with a shortcut on my powerstrip.